# Using Spring DI concepts in Eclipse RCP application

Tags: spring-mvc, eclipse-rcp

I have been wondering how can we use spring in RCP applications. There are things like google Guice which is been used widely for DI in RCP(at least in place where i work).

As a fan of Spring frame work, i tried it in using Spring for DI. 
As an example i spring injection for simple classes,Handlers,views and other stuffs which are the part eclipse RCP with customization.

I am in what way we can make spring as a fully supporting DI framework in RCP.
Please if some one has tried please help me to achieve this idea.

As a start up i have developed simple RCP application using spring DI.

Comment: Eclipse 4 has its own direct injection code.

Comment: yes... I know that eclipse4 gives better DI. But what if some one using eclipse 3.x??? If an application developed in 3.x and it may require lot of time in migrating in that case we have to use external DI framework.